# Взаимодействие с java приложением

Tags: javascript, java

Есть приложение в котором можно выполнять скрипты на JS. Задача - из этого приложения отправлять e-mail. Хочу написать приложение для отправки email на Java. Приложение работает на OS Windows.

Как организовать взаимодействие JS и java программы? Какие способы взаимодействия существуют?

В JS можно создать ActiveXObject объект и работать с его полями и методами. Можно ли подобным образом организовать работу с Java приложением?

Или необходимо создавать веб-сервис и все запросы к Java приложению отправлять как http-запросы(не очень удобно для локального использования)?

Comment: браузерные ангуляр , реакт, gwt, vue.js и т д на яве писать десктопные приложения - зашквар

Comment: JetBrains и Eclipse Foundation то не в курсе)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете воспользоваться движком [Nashorn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/nashorn/nashorn-java-api.htm)

**Example.java**

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        File script = new File("script.js");
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(script), "UTF8"))) {

            engine.eval(reader);
        }
        catch (ScriptException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class EMail {
        private String addr;
        private String subject;
        private String text;

        public EMail() {}

        public EMail(String addr, String subject, String text) {
            this.addr = addr;
            this.subject = subject;
            this.text = text;
        }

        // Аксессоры

        public void send() {
            System.out.format("Отправка письма с темой '%s' на адрес %s\n", subject, addr);
        }
    }
}
```

**scripts.js**

```
var EMail = Java.type("Example.EMail");
var email = new EMail("test@mail.ru", "Тест", "Проверка");
email.send();
```

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно вызвать именно метод java из js(сторонней программы со своим функционалом), а не вызвать js из java. Программа, которая выполняет js скрип выдает ошибку "Java - определение отсутствует", когда пытаюсь создать экземпляр java класса в скрипте через Java.type.

Comment: Если у _сторонней программы со своим функционалом_ нет механизмов интеграции с Java, то вам этого не добиться. Останется только поднимать web-сервис на Java, а из JavaScript делать к нему http-запросы.